How to calculate runout errors of drills?
Context: For university i have to write a programm that calculates the position and value of an runout error for dirlls.
Idea: My idea is with fourier transformation i only look at the noise and calculate the runout error only of that signal
Problem: The values of the error are way to small to be true. The series i copyed below is made with an "Concentricity standard" (translated with google. basically a bar with 4/100 mm error).
You could use min max functions here but not with an real drill
Values in 1/1000 mm
The calculated error here is 4.0689482653531e-17
1;1174
2;1174
3;1174
4;1174
5;1174
6;1174
7;1174
8;1174
9;1174
10;1174
11;1174
12;1174
13;1176
14;1176
15;1176
16;1176
17;1176
18;1176
19;1176
20;1176
21;1178
22;1178
23;1178
24;1180
25;1178
26;1180
27;1180
28;1180
29;1182
30;1182
31;1182
32;1182
33;1184
34;1184
35;1184
36;1184
37;1186
38;1186
39;1186
40;1186
41;1188
42;1188
43;1188
44;1188
45;1188
46;1188
47;1190
48;1190
49;1190
50;1190
51;1190
52;1192
53;1192
54;1194
55;1194
56;1194
57;1195
58;1195
59;1195
60;1197
61;1195
62;1197
63;1197
64;1199
65;1199
66;1199
67;1199
68;1199
69;1201
70;1201
71;1201
72;1203
73;1203
74;1203
75;1203
76;1205
77;1203
78;1205
79;1205
80;1207
81;1205
82;1207
83;1207
84;1207
85;1207
86;1209
87;1209
88;1209
89;1209
90;1211
91;1211
92;1211
93;1211
94;1213
95;1213
96;1213
97;1213
98;1215
99;1213
100;1215
101;1213
102;1215
103;1215
104;1215
105;1215
106;1215
107;1217
108;1217
109;1217
110;1217
111;1217
112;1217
113;1219
114;1217
115;1219
116;1219
117;1217
118;1219
119;1219
120;1219
121;1220
122;1220
123;1220
124;1219
125;1220
126;1219
127;1219
128;1219
129;1220
130;1220
131;1220
132;1220
133;1220
134;1220
135;1220
136;1220
137;1220
138;1220
139;1220
140;1220
141;1220
142;1220
143;1220
144;1220
145;1220
146;1220
147;1220
148;1220
149;1220
150;1220
151;1219
152;1220
153;1219
154;1219
155;1219
156;1220
157;1219
158;1219
159;1219
160;1220
161;1219
162;1219
163;1219
164;1219
165;1219
166;1217
167;1217
168;1217
169;1217
170;1217
171;1217
172;1217
173;1217
174;1215
175;1215
176;1215
177;1215
178;1215
179;1215
180;1213
181;1213
182;1213
183;1213
184;1213
185;1213
186;1211
187;1213
188;1211
189;1211
190;1209
191;1209
192;1209
193;1209
194;1209
195;1209
196;1209
197;1207
198;1207
199;1207
200;1205
201;1205
202;1205
203;1205
204;1203
205;1205
206;1203
207;1201
208;1201
209;1201
210;1201
211;1201
212;1199
213;1199
214;1199
215;1199
216;1197
217;1197
218;1197
219;1195
220;1197
221;1195
222;1195
223;1195
224;1195
225;1195
226;1194
227;1194
228;1192
229;1192
230;1192
231;1190
232;1192
233;1190
234;1188
235;1190
236;1188
237;1188
238;1186
239;1186
240;1186
241;1186
242;1186
243;1184
244;1184
245;1184
246;1184
247;1182
248;1182
249;1182
250;1180
251;1180
252;1180
253;1180
254;1178
255;1178
256;1178
257;1178
258;1178
259;1178
260;1176
261;1174
262;1174
263;1174
264;1174
265;1172
266;1172
267;1172
268;1172
269;1171
270;1172
271;1172
272;1171
273;1171
274;1171
275;1171
276;1169
277;1169
278;1169
279;1169
280;1167
281;1169
282;1167
283;1167
284;1167
285;1167
286;1167
287;1167
288;1167
289;1165
290;1165
291;1165
292;1165
293;1163
294;1163
295;1163
296;1163
297;1163
298;1163
299;1163
300;1163
301;1161
302;1163
303;1161
304;1161
305;1161
306;1163
307;1161
308;1163
309;1161
310;1161
311;1161
312;1161
313;1161
314;1161
315;1163
316;1161
317;1163
318;1161
319;1161
320;1161
321;1163
322;1161
323;1161
324;1161
325;1163
326;1163
327;1163
328;1161
329;1161
330;1161
331;1161
332;1163
333;1161
334;1163
335;1163
336;1161
337;1163
338;1163
339;1163
340;1163
341;1165
342;1163
343;1163
344;1163
345;1165
346;1163
347;1163
348;1165
349;1165
350;1165
351;1165
352;1165
353;1167
354;1165
355;1167
356;1167
357;1167
358;1167
359;1167
360;1167

You have to look at the graphics manually and find an point for the cutoff, but that is not the Problem. Do you have ideas to improve this or an even better way to solve my problem?
def fourier_analysis(data, cutoff = 10_000):
    n = len(data.Degree)
    fhat = np.fft.fft(data.Distance, n )
    PSD = fhat * np.conj(fhat) / n
    freq = (1 / n) * np.arange(n)
    L = np.arange(1,np.floor(n/2), dtype='int')
    
    
    # Frequenzen filtern 
    yf = np.fft.fft(data['Distance'].values)
    filtered_yf = np.where(np.abs(fft(data['Distance'].values)) < cutoff, 0, yf)
    filtered_noise = np.where(np.abs(fft(data['Distance'].values)) > cutoff, 0, yf)
    
    # Inverse FFT  
    reconstructed_signal = ifft(filtered_yf)
    noise_signal = ifft(filtered_noise)
    return noise_signal , reconstructed_signal , PSD, L , freq

def calc_runout_error(noise_signal):
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    noise = np.real(noise_signal)
    for i , j in enumerate(noise):
        df.loc[i,'x'] = j * np.cos(math.radians(i))
        df.loc[i,'y'] = j * np.sin(math.radians(i))
    center_x = np.mean(df['x'])
    center_y = np.mean(df['y'])
    
    deg = math.degrees(math.atan2(center_y, center_x))

    if deg < 0:
        deg += 360
    
    distance = math.sqrt(center_x**2 + center_y**2)
    
    return deg , distance , df

def show_runout_error(df, cutoff=10_000, plots = False, y_lim_value=500, x_lim_left= -0.01, x_lim_right= 0.1):
    print(df.loc[0,'Filename'])
    # Analysis
    noise_signal , reconstructed_signal , PSD, L , freq = fourier_analysis(df,cutoff)
    deg , distance, df_error = calc_runout_error(noise_signal)
    
    if plots == True:
        min_val = min(df['Distance'].min(), np.real(reconstructed_signal).min()) 
        max_val = max(df['Distance'].max(), np.real(reconstructed_signal).max()) 
    
        # plot results
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,16))
    
        # show original
        plt.subplot(3, 2, 1)
        plt.plot(df['Degree'], df['Distance'])
        plt.title('original data')
        plt.xlabel('deg')
        plt.ylabel('distance')
        plt.ylim(min_val, max_val)
    
        # show filtered
        plt.subplot(3, 2, 2)
        plt.plot(df['Degree'], np.real(reconstructed_signal))
        plt.title('filtered data')
        plt.xlabel('deg')
        plt.ylabel('distance')
        plt.ylim(min_val, max_val)
    
        #show fourier
        plt.subplot(3, 2, 3)
        plt.plot(freq[L], np.real(PSD[L]), color='r', linewidth=2)
        plt.ylim(0,y_lim_value)
        plt.xlim(x_lim_left, x_lim_right)
        plt.title('fourier transformation')
        plt.xlabel('frequency')
        plt.ylabel('power spectrum density (PSD)')
    
        # show scatter
        plt.subplot(3, 2, 4)
        plt.scatter(x=df_error['x'], y=df_error['y'], color='blue', s=5)
        plt.xlabel('x-coordinate')
        plt.ylabel('y-coordinate')
        plt.title('runout error in cartesian')
        plt.grid(True)
        
        # Noise
        plt.subplot(3, 1, 3)
        plt.plot(df.Degree, np.real(noise_signal), color='red')
        plt.title('runout error (noise)')
        plt.xlabel('deg')
        plt.ylabel('distance')
        
        plt.show()
        print('Degree: ', deg , ' Distance: ', distance)

    
    return deg , distance, reconstructed_signal

deg,distance,  reconstructed_signal = show_runout_error(list_df[5],
                        cutoff=2500,
                        plots=True,
                        y_lim_value=20_000,
                        x_lim_right=0.1
                       )


fourier_graphics

This is an interesting problem, and you've already done some good work on it. Unfortunately, it is off topic here on Stackoverflow since it is mostly conceptual in nature, as opposed to being a specific programming problem. My advice is to try engineering.stackexchange.com. You can tag your question mechanical-engineering to help others see what it's about.

Good idea. I made a second post on engineering.stackexchange. I will leave this post up here for a week or something. Maybe someone has something good to add
